# Unit testing a model method in Rails using MiniTest - How to use stubs or mock objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest

I am learning on Rails 3 and I started to to unit testing. After some research I decided to use MiniTest for unit testing.

I have the following model

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  # returns all items that were paid by participant  
  def paid_expenses
    self.items.where(:payee_id => self.id)
  end

  ...

end
```

I'm still in the process of figuring out how to unit test that method. I came up with the test case below.

```
class TestParticipant < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @participant = Participant.new
    @participant.first_name = "Elyasin"
    @participant.last_name = "Shaladi"
    @participant.email = "Elyasin.Shaladi@come-malaka.org"
    @participant.event_id = 1  
  end

  ...

  def test_paid_expenses
    @participant.save!
    item1 = @participant.items.create!( item_date: Date.today, amount: 10, currency: "EUR", exchange_rate: 1, base_amount: 10, payee_id: @participant.id, payee_name: @participant.name )
    item2 = Item.create!( item_date: Date.today, amount: 99, currency: "EUR", exchange_rate: 1, base_amount: 10, payee_id: 99, payee_name: "Other participant" )
    assert_includes @participant.paid_expenses, item1, "Participant's paid expenses should include items paid by himself/herself"
    refute_includes @participant.paid_expenses, item2, "Participant's paid expenses should only include items paid by himself/herself"  
  end

  ...

end
```

That's how far I got, but I don't feel satisfied really. I have the feeling that I could do better than that. I rely on Item object here, but theoretically in unit testing I should not rely on external factors. I thought "stub", "mock", etc. but cannot see how to approach that properly :-(

Do you see a better way to do that? How could I do this using stubs or mock objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to practice the assumption that a unit test should test a model/function isolated from external factors.
So I decided to stub external behavior not inherent to the model. The unit test for the method of the `Participant` model could look like this.

```
def test_paid_expense_items
  item1 = MiniTest::Mock.new
  items = MiniTest::Mock.new
  items.expect :where, [item1], [Hash]
  @participant.stub :items, items do
    assert_includes @participant.paid_expense_items, item1, "Participant's paid expenses should include items paid by himself/herself"
  end
end
```

So far I'm happy with that solution. However feel free to comment if you think you have a better solution or complementary information or any other contribution.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good approach, since you're not testing the actual behaviour of the method anymore, i.e. checking if it does return the items with the correct `payee_id`. I guess you could also check the options hash for this value, but to me this feels too much like duplicating the original code without adding any value. Maybe Unit Testing is a false ideal with methods like this that depend completely on external libraries, and one should just call it an integration test and use factories instead of mocks to create actual items?